# Backbone Collection get Object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

not well versed in Backbone, so understand if I don't explain this completely.

I have a collection I am trying to retrieve. Here is an example of the JSON:

```
{
  "id" : "section-one",
  "href" : "section-one-baseball",
  "divisions" : [
     {
       "name": "Orioles",
       "division" : "AL East"
     }
  ]
}
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get to the sections name. When I put this in the console:

```
BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions")
```

I get back an Object with the name and the division. But if I put this in:

```
BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions.name")
```

I get undefined. This is a matter more likely that I am not sure how to retrieve the name of the Object, and that is why I am looking for some help please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions")[0].name
```

1.BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions") return following

```
[
     {
       "name": "Orioles",
       "division" : "AL East"
     }
]
```

[] is meaning array

2.BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions")[0] return following

```
{
    "name": "Orioles",
    "division" : "AL East"
}
```

{} is meaning object

then you can get value you want like below

```
BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions")[0].name
```

or

```
BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions")[0]["name"]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Will check as answer once it says I can