# Backbone Collection get Object - Part 2

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I asked this question earlier and need some more help.

The question: [Backbone Collection get Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774669/backbone-collection-get-object).

My problem is that the answer only gives me back the first object in the array. How would i get back all of them.

Pretty much, how would I take:

```
{
  "id" : "section-one",
  "href" : "section-one-baseball",
  "divisions" : [
    {
      "name": "Orioles",
      "division" : "AL East"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which I then got help being able to get the name from the divisions like this:

```
BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions.name")
```

Now what I need to do is be able to take multiple names from something like this:

```
{
 "id" : "section-one",
 "href" : "section-one-baseball",
 "divisions" : [
   {
     "name": "Orioles",
     "division" : "AL East"
   },
   {
     "name": "Yankees",
     "division": "AL East"
  ]
}
```

So instead of getting just the first one, I need to be able to get all of them from the divisions.

I am getting the results using underscore `_.each` to retrieve them.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this has already been answered but just to add another option, underscore has a `pluck` method for just this use case, where you want to pluck an attribute from a list. you provied it the list then the name of the property you want to extract. It will then return an array of the property from each each item in the list.

```js
divisions = [{
    name: "Orioles",
    division: "AL East"
  }, {
    name: "Yankees",
    division: "AL East"
  }
]


divisionNames = _.pluck(divisions, "name");

console.log(divisionNames);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had to take this one. This works great and once I used it, it made it much easier to get what I needed. Thank you for posting even after there was an answer I selected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to retrieve multiple items in the divisions, you could access it with the following:

`BaseballTeams.models[0].get("divisions")`

With `_.each`, you are able to get to all items in the `divisions` array, perform some sort of function on that particular item, however, `_.each` doesn't return anything upon completion. What you want to use is `_.map` because that will return a new array of whatever you are iterating over.

source: [Underscore.js - each & map](http://underscorejs.org/#each)